# '@ethereumjs/common' giving error Common is not a constructor

Tags: transactions, ethereumjs

I have installed `"@ethereumjs/common": "^2.0.0",`

And and then using it -

```
import Common from '@ethereumjs/common';
const c = new Common({ chain: 'ropsten' })
```

And getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Common is not a constructor`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `import { Common } from '@ethereumjs/common';`.

Comment: And also `import * as Common from '@ethereumjs/common';`.

Comment: Tried both, but still the same.

Comment: [Their GitHub Project](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-common#usage) suggests that you should import `ethereumjs-common`.

Comment: At the top of that page if you have noticed, they announced `repository moved` and clicking that forwards you to [new](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/tree/master/packages/common) modular transaction. And I am using that one.

Comment: Try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(Common, null, 4))` and see what it gives you.

Comment: prints empty object `{}`

Comment: Try `import * as Common from '@ethereumjs/common';` and then `console.log(JSON.stringify(Common, null, 4))`.

Comment: `{ "__esModule": true, "default": {}}`

Comment: Sounds to me like you haven't properly installed `@ethereumjs/common`.

Comment: I dont think that is the case, however I just deleted `node_modules` and did `npm install` one more time. And I can see on my `package.json`'s `dependencies` section has `"@ethereumjs/common": "^2.0.0"`. Also if I Ctrl+Click `@ethereumjs/common` the editor opens files from `"node_modules/@ethereumjs/common/...."`. Soo I dont think there is problem with installation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like its a bug. I tried to raise the issue to the maintainer repo. You can follow rest of the discussion [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/issues/978).